# plotting image plot using data

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy, matplotlib

I have data in ascii file(file.asc) . I want to plot this data in the 2d image plot.can anybody help me plotting this data sets as shown below

my code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
inpdata=np.loadtxt("file.asc")
plt.imshow(inpdata)
plt.show()
```

It gives someplot but not like as attached
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CJyY.jpg)

Input file is here http://www.file.io/ICdP/download/JV782RdzuTlk

Comment: "sorry, this download link no longer exists :("

Comment: `inpdata` shape is `(3025, 8)`, you want to check if this is expected

Comment: Not sure I understood what you said, but anyway the plot you would like seems rather squared shaped, but the line `inpdata=np.loadtxt("file.asc")` returns a `inpdata` with shape `(3025, 8)`, so no way it will be plotted as you expect.

Comment: So maybe the conversion failed, do you know what shape you expected ?

Comment: Maybe try to read directly from the rsf file https://github.com/ahay/src/issues/130#issuecomment-395801778

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.